# Keep type structure of object

Tags: typescript, object, generics, types

I have a function which transforms an object into another with very specific rules. I guess the following function can serve as an example:

```
interface SomethingWithAValue<T> {
  value: T;
}

function transform(obj) {
  let value = {};
  for(let key in obj) {
    value[key] = obj[key].value;
  }
  return { value };
}
```

This basically transforms an object of type (pseudocode)

```
{
  [key 1]: SomethingWithAValue<type 1>,
  [key 2]: SomethingWithAValue<type 2>,
  ...
  [key n]: SomethingWithAValue<type n>
}
```

into a new object of type (again pseudocode)

```
SomethingWithAValue<{
  [key 1]: type 1,
  [key 2]: type 2,
  ...
  [key n]: type n
}>
```

I still need to add a proper type declaration to `transform`, so what is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you need [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).

Here's how you use a mapped type to represent the mapping from a regular object to one in which all the property values are wrapped in `SomethingWithAValue<>`:

```
type SomethingMapper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: SomethingWithAValue<T[K]>
}

type Example = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}
type SomethingMappedExample = SomethingMapper<Example>;
// { 
//   a: SomethingWithAValue<string>; 
//   b: SomethingWithAValue<number>; 
// }
```

And here's how you use inference from mapped types to type the function which unwraps:

```
function transform<T>(obj: SomethingMapper<T>): T {
  // implementation
}
declare let mappedExample: SomethingMappedExample;
const unwrapped: Example = transform(mappedExample); // okay
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me! I had to use some casting (I believe it is called type assertion in TS) within the implementation, but it works!